# Looping through Dynamic JSON String

Tags: jquery, json

I have a POST request which receives a JSON String as a result. The fields, the values, or how deep the array is? These all are unknown. So, I need to loop through each of the json value, its index and its value and perform actions based on it.

```
$.post(
    "test.php", 
    { action: 'someaction', param: '2' },
    function(data) {
      //now data is a json string
      $.each(data, function() {
       key = data.key; //i need to retrieve the key
       value = data.value; //i need to retrieve the value also

       //now below here, I want to perform action, based on the values i got as key and values
      }
    },
    "json"
);
```

How can i get the values of JSON seperated as `key` and `value`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry, guys, but I solved it myself. Please dont be angry with me. (I will delete the question if it is required by the community.)

```
$.post(
    "test.php", 
    { action: 'someaction', param: '2' },
    function(data) {
      //now data is a json string
      $.each(data, function(key,value) {
       alert(key+value);
       //now below here, I want to perform action, based on the values i got as key and values
      }
    },
    "json"
);
```

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution. You should select this as answer.

Answer (score 3):

Well, JSON gets parsed into JavaScript objects. You can traverse them using [**`for...in`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in):

```
for(var key in data) {
    if(data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var value = data[key];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help: [Iterating a JavaScript object's properties using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096924/iterating-a-javascript-objects-properties-using-jquery)