# How to iterate over this hash?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this code

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/cgi-bin/ajax.pl",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: { "id" : id },

    // ...

    success: function(result){
    if (result.error) {
        alert('result.error: ' + result.error);
    } else {
        printObject(result);
    }
    }
});
```

where `printObject` outputs

```
responseText: Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

{"276":"{\"var1\":[\"he\"],\"var2\":[\"he\",\"ki\",\"mt\"],\"var3\":\"07/06-2011\",\"var4\":[],\"var5\":\"ind\"}", ...
```

**Question**

How do I iterate over this hash?

Each array should just be treated as one variable. Ie. `var2` would be `he,ki,mt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result you got should already be parsed as json and it is available in `result` object. Just do `result.276.var2` to get the array.

Comment: When I get `result` I don't know the name of the keys. How can iterate over it? In perl would it be `foreach my $k (keys %hash) { print "$k $hash{var2}";}` But how is this done in JavaScript/JQuery?

Comment: use `$.each` method passing the result as first arg.

Comment: Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096924/iterating-a-javascript-objects-properties-using-jquery