# Matching 2 array values in highcharts pie charts

Tags: jquery, json

I have pie chart here created by using highchart and then I hope when the pie chart area clicked, the console will write some data base on the criteria I have set using "if else".

So I have 2 json data which is here:

```
var json = {
    "data": [
        {
        "topic": "Manchester United F.C.",
        "id": "/en/manchester_united_fc",
        "type": "/soccer/football_team",
        "audience": [
            {
            "userid": "100003921730958",
            "source": "Manchester United",
            "category": "Professional sports team"}
        ]},
    {
        "topic": "Chelsea F.C.",
        "id": "/en/chelsea_fc",
        "type": "/soccer/football_team",
        "audience": [
            {
            "userid": "100003921730958",
            "source": "Frank Lampard",
            "category": "Athlete"},
        {
            "userid": "100003914111287",
            "source": "Chelsea Football Club",
            "category": "Professional sports team"}
        ]}
    ]
};


var jsonFB = {

    "user1": [
        {
        "id": "100003921730958",
        "name": "Tan Jercia",
        "favorite_teams": [
            {
            "id": "19034719952",
            "name": "Real Madrid C.F."},
        {
            "id": "7724542745",
            "name": "Manchester United"}
        ],
        "interested_in": [
            "female",
            "male"
            ],
        "likes": {
            "data": [
                {
                "name": "Corrinne May",
                "category": "Musician/band",
                "id": "17393005071",
                "created_time": "2012-07-04T05:56:47+0000"},
            {
                "name": "Men In Black",
                "category": "Movie",
                "id": "168169803229342",
                "created_time": "2012-06-06T21:21:19+0000"},
            {
                "name": "Pubbing",
                "category": "Interest",
                "id": "106265502743004",
                "created_time": "2012-05-28T07:04:17+0000"},
            {
                "name": "Sleeping",
                "category": "Public figure",
                "id": "102168219824412",
                "created_time": "2012-05-28T07:03:58+0000"},
            {
                "name": "Lionel Messi",
                "category": "Interest",
                "id": "105543199478544",
                "created_time": "2012-05-28T07:03:37+0000"},
            {
                "name": "David Villa Sánchez",
                "category": "Athlete",
                "id": "20714737025",
                "created_time": "2012-05-28T07:03:18+0000"},
            {
                "name": "Frank Lampard",
                "category": "Athlete",
                "id": "115714874568",
                "created_time": "2012-05-28T10:15:04+0000"},
            {
                "name": "Real Madrid C.F.",
                "category": "Professional sports team",
                "id": "19034719952",
                "created_time": "2012-05-28T07:02:57+0000"},
            {
                "name": "Manchester United",
                "category": "Professional sports team",
                "id": "7724542745",
                "created_time": "2012-05-28T07:02:22+0000"},
            {
                "name": "Badminton",
                "category": "Sport",
                "id": "112285278784684",
                "created_time": "2012-05-28T07:02:16+0000"},
            {
                "name": "Swimming",
                "category": "Sport",
                "id": "109717462380351",
                "created_time": "2012-05-28T07:02:13+0000"},
            {
                "name": "The Vampire Diaries - Tv Series/Books",
                "category": "Community",
                "id": "133372903419059",
                "created_time": "2012-05-28T06:37:38+0000"},
            {
                "name": "Gossip Girl",
                "category": "Tv show",
                "id": "8811587900",
                "created_time": "2012-05-28T06:37:38+0000"},
            {
                "name": "Dear John",
                "category": "Movie",
                "id": "154526009569",
                "created_time": "2012-05-28T06:37:37+0000"},
            {
                "name": "The Vow",
                "category": "Movie",
                "id": "131563483577190",
                "created_time": "2012-05-28T06:37:37+0000"},
            {
                "name": "Harry Potter",
                "category": "Movie",
                "id": "156794164312",
                "created_time": "2012-05-28T06:37:36+0000"},
            {
                "name": "Avengers",
                "category": "Movie",
                "id": "126757470715601",
                "created_time": "2012-05-28T06:37:36+0000"},
            {
                "name": "Batman: The Dark Knight",
                "category": "Movie",
                "id": "12887942787",
                "created_time": "2012-05-28T06:37:35+0000"},
            {
                "name": "The Transporter",
                "category": "Movie",
                "id": "105485349484433",
                "created_time": "2012-05-28T06:37:34+0000"},
            {
                "name": "Ip Man",
                "category": "Movie",
                "id": "104108312958644",
                "created_time": "2012-05-28T06:37:33+0000"},
            {
                "name": "How to Train Your Dragon",
                "category": "Movie",
                "id": "96698020019",
                "created_time": "2012-05-28T06:37:33+0000"},
            {
                "name": "Battleship",
                "category": "Movie",
                "id": "116119711759494",
                "created_time": "2012-05-28T06:37:32+0000"},
            {
                "name": "Inception",
                "category": "Movie",
                "id": "91290503700",
                "created_time": "2012-05-28T06:37:32+0000"},
            {
                "name": "John Carter",
                "category": "Movie",
                "id": "192790732230",
                "created_time": "2012-05-28T06:37:31+0000"},
            {
                "name": "Transformers 3",
                "category": "Movie",
                "id": "118936754809410",
                "created_time": "2012-05-28T06:37:31+0000"},
            {
                "name": "Snow White and the Huntsman",
                "category": "Movie",
                "id": "186450181387455",
                "created_time": "2012-05-28T06:37:30+0000"},
            {
                "name": "This Means War",
                "category": "Movie",
                "id": "290847887611269",
                "created_time": "2012-05-28T06:37:29+0000"},
            {
                "name": "Harry Potter",
                "category": "Book",
                "id": "107641979264998",
                "created_time": "2012-05-28T06:37:29+0000"},
            {
                "name": "Love Story",
                "category": "Book",
                "id": "109789932381273",
                "created_time": "2012-05-28T06:37:28+0000"},
            {
                "name": "Justin Bieber",
                "category": "Musician/band",
                "id": "67253243887",
                "created_time": "2012-05-28T06:37:28+0000"},
            {
                "name": "Kelly Clarkson",
                "category": "Musician/band",
                "id": "18481194560",
                "created_time": "2012-05-28T06:37:26+0000"},
            {
                "name": "Jessie J",
                "category": "Musician/band",
                "id": "145300805513355",
                "created_time": "2012-05-28T06:37:26+0000"},
            {
                "name": "Katy Perry",
                "category": "Musician/band",
                "id": "7126051465",
                "created_time": "2012-05-28T06:37:25+0000"}
            ],
            "paging": {
                "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/100003921730958/likes?limit=5000&offset=5000"
            }
        }}
    ]
};​
```

So basically I hope I retrieve the name of the user and write into the console when I clicked the pie chart area by matching both userid which i tried to use loop array matching method. however it doesn't work. :(

```
plotOptions: {
    pie: {
        allowPointSelect: true,
        cursor: 'pointer',
        point: {
            events: {
                click: function() {
                    for (i = 0; i < jsonFB.user1[i]; i++) {

                        for (j = 0; j < json.data[j].audience[j]; j++) {

                            if (jsonFB.user1[i].id == json.data[j].audience[j].userid) {

                                var name = jsonFB.user1[i].name;
                                console.log(name);
                            }
                            else {

                                console.log("false");
                            }

                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        },​
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `for` conditions:

```
for (i = 0; i < jsonFB.user1[i]; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < json.data[j].audience[j]; j++) {
```

I think you meant to iterate over all `user1`s and (`data`s and) `audience`s, right?

```
for (i = 0; i < jsonFB.user1.length; i++) {
    for (k = 0; k < json.data.length; k++) {
        for (j = 0; j < json.data[k].audience.length; j++) {
```

Now your (adapted) `if` will work:

```
if (jsonFB.user1[i].id == json.data[k].audience[j].userid) {
```

I must point out, however, that this will just ensure that usernames will be printed out to the console once for each match between `json` and `jsonFB` data. There's no relation whatsoever with what was clicked in the chart. Check the [Highcharts API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.click) for that. I'm afraid you'll have to work out the specifics by yourself, but I suggest starting at `event.point` (the info you need seems to be there):

```
click: function(event) {
    console.log(event.point);
```

[This demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-ajax/) might also be helpful.

**Update:** If you have more than one user (like `user1`, `user2` etc) you can iterate them like:

```
$.each(jsonFB, function(prop, value) {
    if ( prop.indexOf("user") == 0 ) { // Check if the name starts with "user"
        for (i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {...} // Replaces jsonFB.user1.length
    }
});
```

Comment: What if I wanted to add one more user into "JSONFB"?
Does my code need add another loop for it to check its user first?

So it becomes 

for (var s=0; s<.jsonFB.length; s++){

Comment: the continues as what you state above?

Comment: @user1914667 yes, but if your users are **properties** (instead of elements of a list) - like `user1`, `user2` etc - then the way of iterating is different. Since you're using jQuery, the easiest way would be `$.each(jsonFB, function(prop,value) { ... })`, but you can also use `for ( var prop in jsonFB ) { ... }`. See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1096924/520779) for more info. See also the updated answer.