# Javascript - iterating throught array

Tags: javascript

Hi i have following code

```
$(args.data0).find('group').each( function() ...
```

Variable args is create by AJAX call and it contains data0, data1, ... dataN
How can i programatically iterate over all these variables?
Something like that packed in some kind of forEach cycle :)

```
$(args.data0).find('group').each( function() ...
$(args.data1).find('group').each( function() ...
$(args.dataN).find('group').each( function() ...
```

Many thanks

Comment: You could iterate object args.
There is posted [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096924/iterating-a-javascript-objects-properties-using-jquery)

Comment: you mean with pure javascript?? because thats that each function does

Comment: Fix the source data so that it contains an array instead of an object with properties with a pattern based name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for(var i = 0; i <= n; i++){
    $(args['data' + i]).find('group').each( function() ...
}
```