# How to display each element in Json object using $.each without providing every element separately

Tags: jquery, json, each

My Following code is working fine but I have to hard code each element separately.

How to display each element (**myElement** as shown below) in Json object using $.each without providing every element separately.

```
function getList() {
    $.getJSON("MY_CONTROLLER_URL",function(data){   
        if(data) {
        var json_data;
            $.each(data, function(i,myObject){
                    debugger;
        json_data = '<li><a href="#">'+myObject.myElement+'</a></li>';

        $(json_data).appendTo('#list-data');
        });
        } 
    });
```

Comment: Can you provide the JSON?

Comment: what do you mean by saying "without providing every element separately" ? I don't really get what you want

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096924/iterating-a-javascript-objects-properties-using-jquery

Comment: myObject = {myElement1="abc", myElement2="qrt", myElement3="xyz",... }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var x = {
  a: "Hello",
  b: "World"
}
```

Then you can use

```
Object.keys(x) // => ["a", "b"]

[].forEach.call(Object.keys(x), function(inst){
       console.log(x[inst]); // Will output a and then b
    });
```