# How to iterate the objects in array in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a JSON object:

```
[{
     name:'bhavani',
     age:'19',
     gender:'Female'
},{
     name:'bhavani',
     age:'19',
     gender:'Female'
},{
     name:'bhavani',
     age:'19',
     gender:'Female'
}, {
     // and so on
}]
```

Now i need to access the `name` in each object in this array in a JSP page. I am unable to do it. Can anyone solve this problem for me please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterating a JavaScript object's properties using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096924/iterating-a-javascript-objects-properties-using-jquery)

Comment: `array.forEach(function(e) { console.log(e.name); });`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/921789/how-to-loop-through-javascript-object-literal-with-objects-as-members

Comment: Marcus, @Ole Note that the OP wants to loop over an array of objects, not the properties of an object.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/9xftoqkL/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To loop over an array or an object's properties you can use the `$.each` function.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AtheistP3ace/ohswrnmn/

```
var data = [{
    name: 'bhavani',
    age: '19',
    gender: 'Female'
}, {
    name: 'bhavani',
    age: '19',
    gender: 'Female'
}, {
    name: 'bhavani',
    age: '19',
    gender: 'Female'
}, ];

var $test = $('#test');
$.each(data,
    function (index, value) {
        $test.append(value.name + ' ');
    }
);
```

jQuery docs: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Example looping over array and each objects properties:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AtheistP3ace/ohswrnmn/1/

```
var data = [{
    name: 'bhavani',
    age: '19',
    gender: 'Female'
}, {
    name: 'bhavani',
    age: '19',
    gender: 'Female'
}, {
    name: 'bhavani',
    age: '19',
    gender: 'Female'
}, ];

var $test = $('#test');
$.each(data,
    function (index, value) {
        $test.append(index + ': ');
        $.each(value,
            function (index2, value2) {
                $test.append(value2 + ' ');
            }
        );
        $test.append(' - ');
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has no meaning here, just map your array:

```
var names = arr.map(function(o){
   return o.name; 
});
```

[-jsFiddle-](http://jsfiddle.net/gktjfaht/)