# Loop through object with nested $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, object, nested-loops

I'm having trouble looping through an object using a nested $.each. The object is a series of object of the same type/class nested under rootObject.

**The object**

```
var rootObject ={};

rootObject.reportObject1.name = "reportObject1 Name";
rootObject.reportObject1.prop1 = "reportObject1 Prop1_Value";
rootObject.reportObject1.prop2 = "reportObject1 Prop2_Value";

rootObject.reportObject1.reportObjectA.name = "reportObjectA Name";
rootObject.reportObject1.reportObjectA.prop1 = "reportObjectA Prop1_Value";
rootObject.reportObject1.reportObjectA.prop2 = "reportObjectA Prop2_Value";
```

**The Loop**

```
$.each(rootObject, function(index0, value0){
  console.log(value0.name);

  $.each(value0, function(index1, value1){
    console.log(value1.name);
  }

}
```

**The Problem**

1. `value1.name` is returning object properties other than name in the loop. It's seemingly attempting to return value.name for `prop1` & `prop2`, resulting in "undefined" values.
2. When looking into the value of `value0` during debugging, `value0` appears to loose its value as it enters the nested loop. I.e at `console.log(value1.name)`, `value0`, from the parent loop, becomes `undefined`;
3. When looking into the child loop (`index1, value1`) during debugging, I see that `value1` now equals `value0.name`, and `index1` equals "name".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can automatically define properties *one* level deep, but for two you need to stop and instantiate the parent:

```
var rootObject ={};

rootObject.reportObject1 = {}; // HERE
rootObject.reportObject1.name = "reportObject1 Name";
rootObject.reportObject1.prop1 = "reportObject1 Prop1_Value";
rootObject.reportObject1.prop2 = "reportObject1 Prop2_Value";

rootObject.reportObject1.reportObjectA = {}; // and HERE
rootObject.reportObject1.reportObjectA.name = "reportObjectA Name";
rootObject.reportObject1.reportObjectA.prop1 = "reportObjectA Prop1_Value";
rootObject.reportObject1.reportObjectA.prop2 = "reportObjectA Prop2_Value";
```

Without that, none of these properties are actually getting defined, leading to your `undefined` results.

The next issue is another syntax problem: you're missing closing parentheses on the two `$.each()` calls:

```
$.each(rootObject, function(index0, value0){
  console.log(value0.name);

  $.each(value0, function(index1, value1){
    console.log(value1.name);
  }); // HERE

}); // and HERE
```

With these two fixes, your console output shows:

```
reportObject1 Name
undefined (x3)
reportObjectA Name
```

To get the correct output, or at least some sample output, you could use this little gem ([from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14242550/74757)). Because your structure could potentially have more than two levels, recursion seems appropriate here.

```
function enumerate(o,s){

    //if s isn't defined, set it to an empty string
    s = typeof s !== 'undefined' ? s : "";

    //iterate across o, passing keys as k and values as v
    $.each(o, function(k,v){

        //if v has nested depth
        if(typeof v == "object"){

            //write the key to the console
            console.log(s+k+": ");

            //recursively call enumerate on the nested properties
            enumerate(v,s+"  ");

        } else {

            //log the key & value
            console.log(s+k+": "+String(v));
        }
    });
}
```

If you try `enumerate(rootObject)`, you will get:

```
reportObject1: 
   name: reportObject1 Name
   prop1: reportObject1 Prop1_Value
   prop2: reportObject1 Prop2_Value
   reportObjectA: 
     name: reportObjectA Name
     prop1: reportObjectA Prop1_Value
     prop2: reportObjectA Prop2_Value
```

Comment: 1. Clarification, I'm actually instantiating the parents using a constructor:

`rootObject.reportObject1.reportObjectA = new reportObject();`

I see values when I print `rootObject` using console.log


2. I have the closing parenthesis in my code. I forgot to enter it in this example.

Comment: 2. I have the closing parenthesis in my code. I forgot to enter it in this example.

Comment: 3. Where is the `undefined (x3)` coming from? That bit is accurate in my results, but why is it printing those properties?

Comment: The enumerate function did it! I need to work through it and ID what's going on there.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you happen to have recommendations/references on improving oneself with javascript/jquery?