# how to access regular json object values

Tags: jquery, json

{status: '202', data: {…}}

data: {1: 'Sector-5', 2: 'Sector-20', 3: 'abc', 4: 'Kalka', 5: 'Pinjore', 6: 'Sector-14', 7: 'Sector-7', 8: 'MDC', 9: 'WPS', 10: 'cde', 11: 'efg'}
status: "202"

how to access data object all value in jquery

Comment: Assume you haven't tried anything? How are you receiving/calling this `json` data?

Comment: i try to access it by  if (response.status == '202') {
                    $(response.data).each(function(key,value){
                        // console.log(value);
                      });
                } where  response = JSON.parse(result);

Comment: [Iterating a JavaScript object's properties using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1096924/2943403)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterating a JavaScript object's properties using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096924/iterating-a-javascript-objects-properties-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the following data structure:

```
var result = {
  data: {
    1: 'Sector-5',
    2: 'Sector-20',
    3: 'abc', 
    4: 'Kalka', 
    5: 'Pinjore', 
    6: 'Sector-14', 
    7: 'Sector-7', 
    8: 'MDC', 
    9: 'WPS', 
    10: 'cde', 
    11: 'efg'
  },
  status: "202"
}
```

Then you can access it as follows.

```
if (result.status == '202') {
  $.each(result.data, function(key, value){
    console.log(value);
  });
}
```

See more: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Comment: did in same way but got value = [object] which is shown as  {
    1: 'Sector-5',
    2: 'Sector-20',
    3: 'abc', 
    4: 'Kalka', 
    5: 'Pinjore', 
    6: 'Sector-14', 
    7: 'Sector-7', 
    8: 'MDC', 
    9: 'WPS', 
    10: 'cde', 
    11: 'efg'
  }

Comment: @AmitDhiman this would suggest that your data structure is not what you stated. Sounds like you have an Object with Objects contained within. Update your question with a proper example of the data being returned from PHP.